# Microsoft Excel ODBC Excel 2016 - how to fix?

Tags: excel, odbc

I inherited an Excel macro that works fine in Excel 2013 (file is saved in XLS format and appears to use a 32-bit ODBC Microsoft Excel driver) and I get the following error when trying to run the same macro in Excel 2016 which appears to use a 64-bit Excel driver.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

The code that is failing is below, it specifically highlights the ".Open" in the "With cn" section.  Thoughts on reconfiguring this for the new Excel?

```
Function ReportGroup(strSQL33 As String) As Recordset
    Dim ocmd As Command
    Set ocmd = New Command
    Dim ors As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim r As Long
    Dim intIndx As Long
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";"
    Set ors = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set ors = New Recordset
    'The connection
    With cn
        .Provider = "MSDASQL"
        .ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
        "DBQ=" & strFile & "; ReadOnly=False;"
        .Open
    End With
    With ocmd
      .CommandText = strSQL33
      .CommandType = adCmdText
      .ActiveConnection = cn
      Set ors = .Execute
    End With
    Set ReportGroup = ors
End Function
```

Comment: If your observation is correct you may want to install the corresponding 64Bit ODBC driver (on Windows level) and use it instead. Is the any reason to open/connect to the other xls file via ODBC instead of as a xls workbook?

Comment: To clarify, the Excel 2013 is being run on a different computer than the computer I am running Excel 2016 on.  The operating system for the Excel 2013 copy is Windows Server 2008 R2 and the operating system for Excel 2016 copy is Windows 10.

Comment: When I use ODBC in Excel (e.g. as connection via PowerQuery) and share this Excel file to run on another computer, I have to make sure there is a ODBC connection with the same “credentials”available on the other computer as well. Also, the ODBC driver has to match with Excel (32bit vs 64Bit; e.g. I have both setup on my Windows PC for different applications).  However, if you are using the ODBC to connect to another Excel file, you may have an alternative to connect without ODBC. With PowerQuery the change of source is no problem.  For your VBA code, you may need to test it.

Comment: @Anonymous thanks for the comments - this file is simply connecting to itself, there is a tab of data in a database format that gets summarized into another tab and the programmer apparently used Excel ODBC SQL as a way to summarize the data.

Comment: Maybe you could try to test by setting up a connection to that xls file through DSN via the ODBC Data Source Administrator in both versions 32bit and 64bit (after choosing DSN there should be ODBC Microsoft Excel as available entry). After setup try to use them in another Excel file to connect. If it is working then it should not be a driver issue but may need to adjust the connection string in the code?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at @Anonymous suggestions, I used external connections to show me a connection string.  When executing my macro this did not error and appears to have processed the SQL properly.

```
With cn
    .ConnectionString = "DSN=Excel Files;" & _
    "DBQ=" & strFile & "DriverId=1046; ReadOnly=False;"
    .Open
End With
```

Comment: Great, it worked out!